# htaccess exclusions don't work

Tags: .htaccess, magento

the second exclusion **( !/example-folder )** in the htaccess file doesn't work. What am I missing here?

CMS: Magento

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/example-subfolder/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^index.php/.*/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are you sure it don't work? Note that the rewrite only kicks in if the URL contains two slashes in the path info part.

Answer (score 1):

What is your server? Is it apache or Ngnix? 
Rewrite engine won't work with ngnix, you may have to update the ngnix conf files for this to work.